# How to use multiple tenses in one sentence

Tags: tense, clauses

So if I have a complex sentence that requires multiple tenses, how would I form that properly like if you were to say something like

> They won the battle, but they will not win the war.

or

> While I was at the store, I bought a ham, which I will make for dinner tomorrow.

How would you do this in writing? And is it different from speaking (since there are two past tense forms)?

Answer (score 3):

German is very lax with tenses, having an English speaker go nuts about German tenses is something I consider impossible. It's always the other way round.

*They won the battle, but they will not win the war.*

> Sie haben die Schlacht gewonnen, aber sie werden den Krieg nicht gewinnen.

That example matches English nearly 1:1, with the exception *Perfekt* is used in German as this sentence is obviously taken from speech.

*While I was at the store I bought a ham, which I will make for dinner tomorrow.*

> Als ich im Laden war habe ich einen Schinken gekauft, den ich morgen zum Essen mache.

Again, this is obviously taken from speech, so *Perfekt*. And *Präsens* in the relative clause because *Futur I* is reserved for cases where we don't have a marker word as *morgen*.

Comment: Agreed, for all the difficulties of the German language, usage of tense (or even aspect) is pretty primitive compared to English. As a German learning English, getting a good feeling for tense and aspect was one of the harder parts for me.